# How to add space between words and punctuation in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column (string) in a dataframe with multiple spaces between words and punctuation.
I need to:

1. Add space between punctuation
2. Remove duplicated spaces

Punctuation I am looking for is `/+-`.

My dataframe:

```
col A
'this/is a+ string'
'this+is+a    string'
```

The output I expect:

```
col B
'this / is a + string'
'this + is + a string'
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this is in two steps : first, add space between pontuation, then check to see if there are any continuous spaces. For first step I used a function called `punctuation_space` to pass as "repl" argument to `re.sub()`.

```
import re

def punctuation_space(match_obj):
    """ return whatever matched surrounded by spaces """

    return ' ' + match_obj.group() + ' '

def fn(string):

    # first step
    string = re.sub(r'[+/-]', punctuation_space, string)

    # second step
    return re.sub(r' {2,}', ' ', string)
```

To check the above code :

```
import pandas as pd
original_col = ['this/is a+ string', 'this+is+a    string']

s = pd.Series(original_col)
print(s)
print(s.apply(fn))
```

Output :

```
0      this/is a+ string
1    this+is+a    string
dtype: object
0    this / is a + string
1    this + is + a string
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
df['col A'] = df['col A'].apply(lambda y: " ".join((re.sub(r'([+/-])', lambda x: ' ' + x.group()+' ' , y)).split()) , 1)
```

OR:

```
df['col A'] = df['col A'].str.replace(r'([+/-])',  lambda x: ' ' + x.group()+' ', regex=True).apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.split()))
```